# Should I turn off heat in my home when I am finishing my basement?

Tags: hvac, basement, construction

I live in Virginia and it’s pretty cold here. We are finishing our basement and I turned off the heat. The reason for that is that last time when we finished our basement, we did not turnoff the heat and as a result everybody in the house got sick because of the construction dust coming into living areas. This time to be extra careful, we turned off heat and I closed all the ducts in the house. This might be an overkill to turn off the heat when ducts are closed but I would like to seek an advice to see if this is the best course of action. It’s freezing in home but at same time I don’t want the dust to come into living area and make everyone sick.

Comment: Everyone got sick from dust or got sick from a sick person breathing near the furnace return?

Comment: Call up an HVAC technician to assess the situation. You shouldn't have to turn off your furnace. Be careful to not freeze your pipes and make the situation even worse!

Comment: @monkeyzeus: from dust

Comment: Not clear if you're doing DIY or having a pro, but when demo and drywall is going on, having an industrial aircleaner (for example, BuildClean) is a blessing. If you're DIY, you'd never buy one, but rental might be an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My cousin is an HVAC contractor and always recommends that people *NOT* have their HVAC running while drywall is going up in order to prevent all the sanding dust from clogging up the furnace/duct work. He even offers to temporarily install an old system that he's got if it's necessary to provide heat to the structure.

It will take heat for interior coats (drywall mud, paint, caulk, etc) to dry/cure properly, so you'll need to provide some sort of heat. Also, if you're living in the house, *you* will need some sort of heat. This can be temporary electric or propane heat if necessary. Be ***exceedingly cautious*** if using any sort of temporary gas heat to ensure adequate ventilation so you don't kill yourself (some consider this worse than getting sick), and that you don't burn down the house (remember, the propane is *burning* to provide heat).

You may consider temporarily blocking off all return air ducts coming *from* the areas being refinished in order to help keep the dust from being sucked into your heating system. You may also want to invest in higher quality HEPA rated filters for your furnace, at least while you're doing the renovation work, and change them more frequently knowing that no matter how well you seal off the work area, some dust will leak through into the rest of the house.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the right tools and accessories you can finish your basement and leave the heat on. For example, you can use a chop saw for cutting 2 X 4's if you buy one that has a discharge that will accept the hose from a shop vac. turn on the vac and the saw and there will be very little dust. When dry wall finishing get a professional finisher that has a vacuum attached or have it finished by someone that has one. I know that what I wrote works, since that is what I did and it was finished during the winter months with little dust just north of Pittsburgh, Pa.  Hope this helps.